# react redux router display blank page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, redux

I have index.js like:

```
render(
    <Root store={store} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

and `Root.js` like:

```
   class Root extends Component {
  render() {
    const { store } = this.props
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
          <ReduxRouter />
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}

Root.propTypes = {
  store: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

export default Root
```

and my `routes.js` like:

```
export default (
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
  </Route>
)
```

and my `App.js` like:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    <div>
      <p>Some cool header</p>
    </div>
  }
}
export default App
```

But when I access my web via `localhost:3000` it just show the blank page.. I expect it to show `<p>Some cool header</p>`

It does not give any error.. What is the issue here..

Comment: Are you trying to do server side rendering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not passed any routes to the `ReduxRouter` component inside of the `Root` component render function. This is why `App` is not being rendered and you see a blank page!

Update `Root.js` to something like:

```
import routes from './routes'

class Root extends Component {
  render() {
    const { store } = this.props
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
          <ReduxRouter>
              {routes}
          </ReduxRouter>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}

Root.propTypes = {
  store: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

export default Root
```

You should then see the desired output in your browser.